# WordPress : Revert theme files after updating through WP-Admin

Tags: php, wordpress

I logged into a site I made a few years back to edit the menu. I used the Editor in WP-Admin to quickly do this, however doing this has deleted some old sliders I had in there but forgot. Edited `header.php` and now can't get it back.

I need to get the files reverted to the old versions of about an hour ago, any idea how? If I was on FTP I could just press undo and re upload but I didn't have FTP access to hand so decided to be clever.

Comment: You mean you did changes to a page or post etc? And you want to revert that back??

Comment: You can undo your theme or plugin files, if you update it though admin.

Comment: I mean theme files that I don't have a backup of. I've edited the header.php and have removed a slider by mistake, updated it and now can't revert :|